# LTSpice not giving expected result

Tags: ltspice

I was expecting I(R1) to be 8.15A

What did I do wrong?
[image]

Comment: V1 isn't connected to ground could be a visual bug

Comment: I updated the ground, still no luck

Comment: You've got the sign flipped  on the dependency. Eg. change gain to -3  or flip V2.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany You are right, thank you!